# laravel set locate currently from web routes

Tags: laravel, locale

why I can't setlocale from file web.php  routes, this's code:

```php
Route::get('language/{lang}', function ($lang) {
    
    App()->setLocale($lang);
    session()->put('locale', $lang);
    return redirect()->back();
    
})->name('langroute');
```

and this one is menu select:

```xml
<li class="nav-item btn-rotate dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLang" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <img width="25" src="{{ asset('assets_front/images/'.App::getLocale().'.png') }}" class="img-responsive img-bandera" alt="@lang('idioma') @lang('navigation.languages-'. App::getLocale())">
    <p>
      <span class="d-lg-none d-md-block">{{ trans_choice('words.idioma', 1) }}</span>
    </p>
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLang">
    @foreach (Config::get('app.languages') as $language)
      @if ($language != App::getLocale())
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('langroute', $language) }}">
          <img width="25" src="{{ asset('assets_front/images/'.$language.'.png') }}" class="img-responsive img-bandera" alt="@lang('idioma') @lang('navigation.languages-'. App::getLocale())">
          @lang('navigation.languages-'. $language)
        </a>
      @endif
    @endforeach
  </div>
</li>
```

what I'm wrong?

Comment: Have you tried with `app()->setLocale(...)` or `App::setLocale(...)` instead of `App()->setLocale(...)`?

Comment: this work App::setLocale($lang); for the moment, but this one  session()->put('locale', $lang); or  Session::put('locale', $lang); not work, why??

Comment: You'r enot using the session anywhere in your view. How can you tell the session helper isn't working?

Comment: hey! I solved myself, I create one middleware, there I added App::setlocale( session()->get('locale') ); and my web.php I added session()->put('locale', $lang); and work

Comment: thanks everyone!!!